# How can I compile LaTeX from a front-end website?

Tags: php, latex, raspberry-pi4

As Overleaf is not lightweight enough to handle LaTeX compiling as a self-hosted service on a Raspberry Pi 4 (ARMv7, 4GB RAM), I'd like to create a small front-end website from which I can:

1. Retrieve LaTeX sources from a git hosted on my RPi;
2. Compile them into a PDF that will be served on my page.

I'm thinking about running the script with PHP (through AJAX), passing options thanks to a small config file within the git project (like BibTeX compiling and multiple compiling to render Tikz and the TOCs).

I think it's feasible, but maybe it's not the best technology to do so (is Node.js more suited?).

There is also the problem about user rights: should the script be run by the `www-data` user? or by a dedicated user (it may require `sudo`)?

Any help is appreciated. :-)

*I'm not sure SO is suited for this kind of open question, but I'm not aware of any other platform to ask this to.*

Comment: Maybe https://tug.org/tug2020/preprints/Tournade-HTTP.pdf could be interessting